# Add Custom Validation Errors in Silverlight

Tags: .net, validation, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

Is there any way to add custom validation errors to the list of control's errors? I know how to use IDataErrorInfo, INotifyErrorInfo, ValidationAttribute, etc, but I would like to add custom validation errors from code.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way:

1. First, create a **public** class for holding our error message:

   public class TagModelError
   {
           private readonly String errorMessage;

   ```
       public TagModelError(String errorMessage)
       {
           this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
       }

       public Object Tag
       {
           get
           {
               return new Object();
           }
           set
           {
               throw new ValidationException(this.errorMessage);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Next, create a helper method:

   public static void AddValidationError(this Control control, String errorMessage)
       {
           var expression = elm.GetBindingExpression(FrameworkElement.TagProperty);

   ```
       if (expression == null)
       {
           expression = control.SetBinding(FrameworkElement.TagProperty, new Binding("Tag")
           {               
               Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
               ValidatesOnExceptions = true,
               UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit,
               Source = new TagModelError(errorMessage)
           }) as BindingExpression;
       }

       expression.UpdateSource();
   }
   ```

I am using the **Tag** property because it is seldom required, but you can use another one. The trick here is to cause an exception when writing back to the model.